# In Unity Plastic SCM see easily which branch is currently checked out

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

We are team just moving over the using Plastic SCM with Unity, from git and LFS. The Unity integration is very important for this change. However I have already made a mistake where I committed changes to the wrong branch.
I see the branches listed under Plastic SCM > Branches, however I don't see which is the currently checked out branch, which is very important information. How do I find this information without exiting Unity? I am missing something simple?

Comment: Can you provide more info please? 
Are you using command-line or PlasticSCM client GUI or handling it from Unity itself?

Comment: The issue here is handling this with Unity integration. I cannot find a simple way to tell from the Unity Plastic panel which branch is currently check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a reply to your explanation in the comments above:
You can view what branch you are in currently by opening the PlasticSCM window in Unity then heading to "Branches". Your current branch would be slightly highlighted.

For example:
[image: Branches tab in PlasticSCM window]

As you can see in the screen above, there is two branches, the one on the top is slightly highlighted which means its my active branch.

Regarding your issue - pushing changes to wrong branch. PlasticSCM gives you a way to move changeset to other branch but sadly you can't achieve that just by using Unity GUI(Yet). If you are interested in solving such issue follow the steps below:

Open PlasticSCM window and head to Branch explorer (Or launch PlasticSCM from your machine without using Unity)
[image: Plastic Nav]

Right click on the changeset > Advanced > Move changeset to a different branch
[image: PlasticSCM GUI branch explorer]

Choose the branch you want and move it.
Note: The branch that you want to move to must be empty. So you might need to create a new empty branch as child to the branch you need, move the changeset then merge it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for this. In the right down corner of the Plastic SCM window.

Image

[image: 1]

Comment: This shows your current changeset but such as `135@Project_Name@ServerName@cloud` but it doesn't show which branch.